# Dart : How to set the preamble file to run on the command-line?

Tags: eclipse, dart, server-side

I used eclipse with dart plugins, when I run "**pub build**", I got the result below.
I had move the built directory to a VPS with Tomcat, the client code runs okay.

How to run the server side code(TreeFilesystemServer.dart)?
Because I had some server side code, the result says I might provide a *preamble file*.
Do I must provide the preamble file? What does preamble file mean?

Thanks in advance!

```
1.My project framework.
Main
--web
  --allyEdit
    --TreeFilesystemServer.dart  <=(this is a server side code)
  --Main.css
  --Main.dart  <=(this is the entry point of client )
  --Main.html
--pubspec.lock
--pubspec.yaml


2.Below is the message when I run pub build.
[Info from Dart2JS]:  
Compiling allyEdit_dart|web/allyEdit/TreeFilesystemServer.dart...  
[Warning from Dart2JS on allyEdit_dart|web/allyEdit/TreeFilesystemServer.dart]:  

When run on the command-line, the compiled output might require a preamble file located in:
<sdk>/lib/_internal/lib/preambles.  

[Info from Dart2JS]:  
Took 0:00:04.534259 to compile allyEdit_dart|web/allyEdit/TreeFilesystemServer.dart.  
Built 1649 files to "build".
```

Comment: I have never heard of such an issue. Can you please provide more information about how your app package directory looks like? Normally all you need is a `pubspec.yaml` file and a `*.dart` file containing the `main()` for server side code and an `index.html` and `some.dart` file in the `web` directory for the client side (at least to start with).
When you then run `pub build` from the directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` file the `web` directory should be built to JavaScript.

Comment: What happens when you call `pub build` from command line?

Comment: You are saying "I must provide..." but the message clearly says that the built was successful and a preamble file MIGHT BE REQUIRED.

Comment: This has probably to do with https://groups.google.com/a/dartlang.org/forum/#!topic/misc/16f1cam4XVA Maybe you have incompatible versions of Dart SDK and Eclipse Dart plugin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A "preamble file" for dart2js compiled output is a javascript file that sets up a JS environment sufficiently similar to that of a browser, so that dart2js output can be run outside of the browser.

The Dart project's tests can be run both in a browser, in the "d8" stand-alone JavaScript shell based on v8, and in "jsshell" which is a stand-alone version of the Mozilla JS engine.
For the last two, the compiled code needs a "preamble file" to be executed before the compiled script. The dart2js preamble files are located in sdk/lib/_internal/compiler/js_lib/preambles - they were moved here semi-recently, so some older references might point to a different location.

If you only run that dart2js compiled code in a browser, you don't need to provide a preamble file.
If you want to test the output in d8, you will need the d8 preamble file (which sets up hooks for printing and simulates timers).